# React Native Api not responding at first time but responding on its second render

Tags: react-native, api, redux, axios

when I hit api first time it giving me response status 200 but not showing any data in its response but if I hit it twice its doing its job perfectly. I am manging API Calls through redux.

Answer (score 0):

As I already phase the same issue you need to return your response from the action Axios response and after that you will get the API response and return that response.

```
export const verifyCode = (data) => async dispatch => {
  try {
      const instance = axios.create();
      const response = await instance.post(API_PATHS.VERIFY_CODE, data);
      dispatch({ type: VERIFY_CODE, payload: response.data });
      return response.data;
  } catch (e) {
      dispatch({ type: VERIFY_CODE, payload: e });
      return Promise.reject(e);
  }
};
```